# LineChart makes PageRouteBuilder transition lag/stutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes, fl-chart

I use a PageRouteBuilder transition between my pages.
Whenever I navigate to a page with a LineChart, that has some data in it the transition begins to stutter and lag.
The lag disappears if I remove the LineChart, so it is definetly causing it.

Did someone encouter a similar issue and is there a fix for this?